# Show that if $C$ is a closed curve then: $\oint\cos(X,n)ds = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Show that if $C$ is a closed curve then:

$$\oint_{C}\cos(X,n)ds = 0$$

Where $s$ is the arc length and $n$ is the outer normal.

I fundamentally do not understand this notation. I have been trying to figure out what $\cos(X,n)$ notates? I assume $n$ is the normal vector to the curve $C$, but how can this be a variable of cosine? If someone could provide some reference as to what this is called, and what it means, this would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not know the notation, but I do believe that this is a (possible) result from a theorem of complex analysis; Cauchy’s Theorem

Comment: This does seem quite exotic. Can you provide any more context on where you found it?

Comment: Dimitrovich Problems in Mathematical Analysis. He makes no mention of the notation in the book. It was originally in Russian, then translated. Not sure if this has some russian-notation specific questions. ...

Comment: Surely the notation is explained in the text somewhere. Try $X$ the position vector and the cosine of the angle between the two vector fields. But that fails for the unit circle, so who knows …

Comment: The statement becomes correct for sure if you use my interpretation but replace $n$ with $T$ (the unit tangent). Then this turns into a standard line integral of a conservative vector field (assuming the curve does not pass through the origin).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which makes sense to me is to let $X$ be the constant unit vector field whose value is $e_1=(1,0)$, and the brackets $(X,n)$ mean the angle between $X$ and $n$ (to be concrete, let us say we measure the angle counter clockwise from $X$ to $n$), so that the cosine of this angle is the same as the inner product of the vectors (since they have unit norm): $\langle X,n\rangle=\cos(X,n)$. In this case, the integral is indeed $0$.

To prove this, let $R:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ be the rotation counter-clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, i.e $R(x,y)=(-y,x)$, and let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^2$ be a $C^1$ (you can reword the argument slightly to account for piecewise $C^1$ parametrization $\gamma$ as well) positive parametrization of the curve $C$, and let $n$ and $T$ be the unit outward normal and the positively oriented unit tangent vectors. Recall that the orientation of these vectors is such that for every point $p$ along the curve, $R(n(p))=T(p)$ (i.e if you rotate the normal anticlockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, you get the tangent). Since rotations preserve the inner products, we have
\begin{align}
\oint_C\cos(X,n)\,ds&=\int_{\gamma}\langle e_1,n\rangle\,ds\\
&=\int_{\gamma}\langle R(e_1),R(n)\rangle\,ds\\
&=\int_{\gamma}\langle e_2,T\rangle\,ds\\
&=\int_a^b\left\langle e_2, \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\|\gamma'(t)\|}\right\rangle\,\|\gamma'(t)\|\,dt\\
&=\int_a^b\gamma_2'(t)\,dt\\
&=\gamma_2(b)-\gamma_2(a)\\
&=0,
\end{align}
where the last line is because $\gamma$ is a closed curve. Note that in this case, all we need is for the vertical coordinate of the curve to remain the same at the endpoints.

---

**Extra Remarks.**

My motivation with this problem was to try to massage whatever is given $\int(\text{stuff})\,ds$ into the form $\int_C \langle F,T \rangle\,ds$, where $F$ is some vector field, and $T$ is the unit tangent to the curve and $ds$ is the length element. The reason is because along the curve,
\begin{align}
\langle F,T\rangle\,ds&=F_1\,dx+F_2\,dy,
\end{align}
and now this can be evaluated by any of the line-integral techniques (either directly or by Stokes/Greens theorem provided $C$ is the boundary of some planar region).

Sometimes, you can try to massage the expression $\int_{\gamma}(\text{stuff})\,ds$ into the form $\int_{\gamma}\langle F,n\rangle\,ds$, because along the curve, one has
\begin{align}
\langle F,n\rangle\,ds=F_1\,dy-F_2\,dx,
\end{align}
so this should also be a straight-forward line integral to evaluate directly. Alternatively if $\gamma$ is the boundary of some planar region $\Omega$, then we can use the divergence theorem (in this case it's nothing but Stokes/Greens theorem) to get $\int_{\gamma}\langle F,n\rangle\,dl=\int_{\Omega}\text{div}(F)\,dA$, where $\text{div}(F)=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}$.